# Print Invoice in C# console application

Tags: c#, formatting, console-application, invoice, receipt

**When the customer adds more and more additives, the "Notes" line will overflow. How can I modify the code of the "Notes" line to break the line every time it overflows and still display full information?**

This is my code:

```
private static void PrintInvoice(Drink drink)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

    // Define a maximum width for each line
    const int lineWidth = 46;

    // Print the header
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/{new string('=', lineWidth)}/");
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/{new string(' ', lineWidth / 2 - 3)}INVOICE{new string(' ', lineWidth / 2 - 4)}/");
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/{new string('=', lineWidth)}/");

    // Print each field dynamically adjusting widths
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/  Date: {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")}");
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/  Customer: {drink.CustomerName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/  Drink: {drink.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/  Notes: Added {drink.GetCustomizations()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/  Total Price: ${drink.Price}");

    // Print the footer
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/{new string('=', lineWidth)}/");
}
```

This is what it look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQf09.png)

Comment: You probably need to do something with `drink.GetCustomizations()` and `lineWidth`. What have you done to solve your problem?

Comment: Creating UIs character by character is hard and will always break the moment the user tries to resize the console. Using tabs for positioning wastes a *lot* of space too. If you *really* need a text UI, consider using a library like [Terminal.Gui](https://github.com/gui-cs/Terminal.Gui) or [Spectre.Console](https://spectreconsole.net/). Both support displaying text in columns and grids, both handle screen resizing and a lot more

Comment: Try iterating over `drink.GetCustomizations()`, printing its elements and adjusting width.

Comment: Is this homework or a real application? Even applications that use POS printers through text mode don't use `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: @Cid Yes! While waiting for the answers, I remembered that there was that part and was able to fix it (temporarily for now )
Here how I fix it:
public string GetCustomizations()
{
    return string.Join("\n\t\t\t\t\t/\t  ", customizations);
}

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you! I will look into it and use it in the near future!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop:

```
var drinkString = $"Notes: Added {drink.GetCustomizations()}";

for ( int i = 0; i < drinkString.Length; i += lineWidth )
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t\t\t/  {drinkString.Substring(i, Math.Min(lineWidth, drinkString.Length - i))}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a free NuGet package is okay, check out [Spectre.Console](https://spectreconsole.net/).

Example

[image]

Note that you can adjust the table width with `private const int tableWidth = 55;`. All colors can be the same, I did some in mixed colors to show possibilities.

```cs
internal partial class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Order order = new Order()
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            Drink = "Espresso",
            Total = 6.5m,
            Note = "Added Espresso Shots x2, Caramel Syrup Pumps x3, Mocha Drizzle, Extra"
        };

        var table = CreateTable();
        
        table.AddRow("[green]Date[/]", $"{DateTime.Now:g}");
        table.AddRow("[green]Customer[/]", order.FirstName);
        table.AddRow("[green]Drink[/]", order.Drink);
        table.AddRow("[green]Notes[/]", order.Note);
        table.AddRow("");
        table.AddRow("[green]Total[/]", $"[yellow]{order.Total:C}[/]");

        AnsiConsole.Write(CreateHeader());
        AnsiConsole.Write(table);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private const int tableWidth = 55;
    public static Table CreateTable()
    {
        var table = new Table()
            .Width(tableWidth)
            .AddColumn("")
            .AddColumn("")
            .Alignment(Justify.Left)
            .HideHeaders()
            .BorderColor(Color.Black);
        return table;
    }
    public static Table CreateHeader()
    {
        var table = new Table()
            .Border(TableBorder.Ascii)
            .Width(tableWidth)
            .Alignment(Justify.Left)
            .BorderColor(Color.Green);

        table.AddColumn(new TableColumn("[green]INVOICE[/]").Centered());



        return table;
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Drink { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```